# validation failed: video_data.0._id: Cast to ObjectId failed for value \"\" (type string) at path \"_

Tags: node.js, arrays, reactjs, mongodb, express

I'm building a React form, and when I make the post request from React then I'm getting error message validation failed: `video_data.0._id: Cast to ObjectId failed for value \"\" (type string) at path \"_`. Here I'm getting data by  `console.log(JSON.stringify(booksStore)+"datahhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhh")` like `this.here` is using two dynamic form. How can I solve this issue?

```js
        {
           "book_rating_count":22,
           "book_review":0,
           "book_like":0,
           "_id":"61b6f8a3ba3b7a3d10d0afe0",
           "book_title":"dgfgh",
           "book_authore":"uytiu",
           "book_overview":"fghfjhhg",
           "book_category":"jhk",
           "book_genre":"Trending Now",
           "book_tag":"comedy",
           "book_languages":"uii",
           "book_duration":"uiuy",
           "book_rating":5,
           "book_publication":"gyhrt",
           "booksEpdf":"https://booksepdf.s3.amazonaws.com/Screenshot%20%28166%29.png",
           "booksAudio":"https://booksaudioes.s3.amazonaws.com/Screenshot%20%28166%29.png",
           "video_data":[
              {
                 "_id":"61b6f8a3ba3b7a3d10d0afe1",
                 "number_of_chapters":1,
                 "video_title":"ghhghggg",
                 "description":"ghghg",
                 "booksVideo":"https://hashvideo.s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/Screenshot%20%28166%29.png",
                 "booksImage":"https://bookstoreimage.s3.amazonaws.com/Screenshot%20%28166%29.png",
                 "releaseDate":null,
                 "subvideo_data":[
                    {
                       "_id":"61b6f8a3ba3b7a3d10d0afe2",
                       "pageNo":1,
                       "subvideo_title":"hhghgghghgg",
                       "subdescription":"vfgv",
                       "booksVideo":"https://hashvideo.s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/Screenshot%20%28166%29.png",
                       "booksImage":"https://bookstoreimage.s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/Screenshot%20%28166%29.png",
                       "subreleaseDate":null
                    },
                    {
                       "_id":"61b6f8a3ba3b7a3d10d0afe3",
                       "subvideo_title":"hhghgghghgg",
                       "subdescription":"hgjhjh",
                       "pageNo":2,
                       "booksImage":"https://bookstoreimage.s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/Screenshot%20%28166%29.png",
                       "booksVideo":"https://hashvideo.s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/Screenshot%20%28166%29.png",
                       "subreleaseDate":"2021-12-13T07:39:15.412Z"
                    }
                 ]
              }
           ],
           "book_created_date":"2021-12-13T07:39:15.414Z"
        }
    here is my mongoose schemawhich im using to save it.
    const mongoose = require('mongoose')
    
    
    const BooksStoreSchema = mongoose.Schema({
        
        book_title : {
             type: String,
              required:[true,"enter your book name"] 
            },
    
        book_authore: { 
            type: String,
            required:[true,"enter your book author name"] 
             },
        
        book_overview: {
             type: String,
               required:[true,"enter your book description"] 
            }, 
        book_publication: {
             type: String,
               required:[true,"enter your book publication name"] 
            },
        book_category: {
            type: String,
            required:[true,"enter book category name"] 
               }, 
               
        book_genre: {
            type: String,
            enum: ["Feel Good Novels", "Trending Now", "Fiction", "Best sellers", "Originals","Internationals"]
               }, 
               
        book_tag: {
            type: String,
            required:true,
            enum: ["comedy","thriller","horror"]
               }, 
        book_rating_count :{
            type:Number,
            default:0
        },
        book_languages :{
            type:String,
            required:true
        },
        book_duration :{
            type:String,
            required:true
        },
        book_rating :{
            type:Number,
            required:true
        },
        booksEpdf:{
            type:String,
            required:true
        },
        booksAudio:{
            type:String,
            required:true
        },
        video_data: [{
                     
                    number_of_chapters:{
                        type:Number,
                        required:true,
                    },
                    video_title: {
                        type:String,
                        required:true
                    },
                    description:{
                        type:String,
                        required:true
                    },
                    booksVideo:{
                        type:String,
                        required:true
                    },
                    booksImage:{
                        type:String,
                        required:true
    
                    },
                    releaseDate:{
                          type: Date,
                          default: Date.now,
                    },
                    subvideo_data: [{
                            pageNo:{
                                type:Number,
                                required:true
                            },
                            
                            subvideo_title:{
                                type:String,
                                required:true
                            },
                            subdescription:{
                                type:String,
                                required:true
                            },
                            booksVideo: {
                                type:String,
                                required:true
                            },
                            booksImage: {
                                type:String,
                                required:true
                            },
                            subreleaseDate:{
                                 type: Date,
                                 default: Date.now,
                            },
                        },
                    ],
                }],
        //like view and created schema..... 
        book_review: {
            type: Number,
            default: 0,
        },
    
        book_like: {
            type:Number,
            default:0
        },
        book_created_date: {
            type: Date,
            default: Date.now,
        },
    
    });
    module.exports = mongoose.model('booksStore', BooksStoreSchema)
     here is my controller....
    router.post('/',    function(req, res,next) {
    
      const booksStore = new BooksStore({
                book_title : req.body.book_title,
                book_authore : req.body.book_authore,
                book_overview : req.body.book_overview,
                book_category : req.body.book_category,
                book_genre :req.body.book_genre,
                book_tag : req.body.book_tag,
                book_languages: req.body.book_languages,
                book_duration : req.body.book_duration,
                book_rating : req.body.book_rating,
                book_publication : req.body.book_publication,
                book_rating_count:req.body.book_rating_count,
                booksEpdf:  req.body.booksEpdf,
                booksAudio: req.body.booksAudio,
                video_data:req.body.video_data,
                book_review:req.body.book_review,
                book_like:req.body.book_like,
                book_created_date:req.body.book_created_date,
               
            });
            console.log(JSON.stringify(booksStore)+"datahhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhh")
            booksStore.save()
                .then(result => {
                    res.status(200).send({
                        _id: result._id,
                         message:"submit successfully"
                    })
                })
                .catch(err => {
                    res.send({ message: err })
                })
                })
```

Actually, I was used dynamic form in react, I want to save this data, please help me how can I solve this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve this kind of issue you need to verify your code, is any _id already declare in your react `this.State`?

If you have declared any _id which does match your database response like this _id then go to your code simply modify it or remove it then try it again. That will work.